# Cognito Forms: Reveal section based on Boolean field response

Tags: cognito-forms

I have created a form section which I would like to be conditional upon a checkbox on a previous field being checked or not. While I have sailed through all aspects of form creation, it seems that this condition is not available. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Cognito Forms does support conditional visibility logic. If the click on the section you would like to conditionally hide/show, in the field settings section on the left there is an option called "Show This Field". Choose the "When" option. This will cause a dialog to open that will allow you to edit when the selected section should be visible to the user.

For more information check out our [Help Topic](http://help.cognitoapps.com/understanding-field-settings-1) regarding this, and other, field settings.